# Yii2 Image upload on server throws an unexpected invalid configuration error

Tags: php, yii2

I am fairly new to yii and just started using `Yii2` on my latest project(I am using `Yii2` basic template btw). My problem right now is an upload image process wherein it is capable of multiple image uploads. On my localhost, it is fine, the images is successfully saved as well as the corresponding record accompanying it. However, the problem is when I have uploaded the website to my test server(linux server with PHP 5.4), the process is throwing an error:

```
Invalid Configuration
An internal server error occurred.
```

The above error occurred while the Web server was processing your request.
Please contact us if you think this is a server error. Thank you.

I already made the necessary folders to have `777 permissions` and still it wont work. I also tried to just create a record without uploading an image and as expected was successful which points directly to the upload process being the culprit.

Here is my code for my model:

```
class UploadImageForm extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var UploadedFile|Null file attribute
     */

    public $file;

    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['file'], 
              'file', 
              'maxFiles' => 10, 
              'extensions' => ['gif', 'jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'JPG', 'JPEG', 'PNG', 'GIF'],
              'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024 * 2
            ], // <--- here!
        ];
    }

}
```

Here is my code for the controller:

```
    public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Hotel();
    $uploadform = new UploadImageForm();
    $hotelcategory = HotelCategory::find()->all();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        $new_id = $model->hotel_id;

        #let us save the images
        $uploadform->file = UploadedFile::getInstances($uploadform, 'file');
        if ($uploadform->file && $uploadform->validate()) {
            foreach ($uploadform->file as $file) {

                $file->saveAs(Yii::$app->basePath .'/web/uploads/images' ."/". $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension);
                $hotel_images = new HotelImages;
                $hotel_images->hotel_image_name = $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension;
                $hotel_images->hotel_image_hotel = $new_id;
                $hotel_images->hotel_image_url = Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('/uploads/images')."/". $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension;
                $hotel_images->save();

            }
        }            
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->hotel_id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'uploadform' => $uploadform,
            'hotelcategory' => $hotelcategory,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Can you point me to what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: can you give me the error message?

Comment: Hi sorry, where can I get the error message? btw the error on the webpage shows this one: Invalid Configuration An internal server error occurred. The above error occurred while the Web server was processing your request. Please contact us if you think this is a server error. Thank you.

Comment: set the debug mode true and get the internal error

Comment: thanks for the response guys, found the culprit after doing some testings, the error is happening on this part : if ($uploadform->file && $uploadform->validate()) { in my controller file.,  when i remove the $uploadform->validate() everything seems to work fine, now I am wondering what could be the problem there? is it because it is set for multiple upload? or am i missing something, tia

Comment: @dency I already set the debug to true but the debugger is not visible on server, only on my localmachine.. btw I am also using prettyurl on this project and have put the site on another directory like: mywebsite.com/yii2dir and everything works fine just the image validate part

Answer (score 1):

*'Invalid Configuration'* error while uploading a file could be related to **'The fileinfo PHP extension is not installed.'**. Try to enable the extension in your php.ini file. After that your validation should also work. I hope this could help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Missing option checkExtensionByMimeType

```
        [['file'], 
          'file', 
          'maxFiles' => 10, 
          'extensions' => ['gif', 'jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'JPG', 'JPEG', 'PNG', 'GIF'],
          'checkExtensionByMimeType'=>false, // <--- here!
          'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024 * 2
        ], 
    ];
}
```

...

Comment: It would help to have an explination of why checkExtensionByMimeType solves this.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and I solved it by just enabling the extension in php.ini.

The Yii2 documentation clearly says:

> getMimeType() throws yii\base\InvalidConfigException
>   when the fileinfo PHP extension is not installed and $checkExtension is false.

For more info click [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basefilehelper.html#getMimeType()-detail)

Hope this helps.